# VPC Route Table entry disappears

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

so I'm trying to add a VM to be visible to a kubernetes cluster in AWS.  An AWS node in my kubernetes cluster has a bridge at 10.244.0.1 and provides that /24 network that all the pods in this k8s cluster are on.  The vpc route table has the 10.244.0.0/24 route with a destination of that VM.  Everything works great in term of routing to those IPs

I boot another VM and I give it an alias of 10.244.10.1

`ifconfig eth0:0 10.244.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.255`

on the k8s node, I start a

`ping 10.244.10.1`

as expected nothing happens (there is no route for it)

I edit the route table to make a 10.244.10.1/32 route with the destination of my new VM and save it.

a bunch of successful pings print out, but then they stop.

`$ ping 10.244.10.1
PING 10.244.10.1 (10.244.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.244.10.1: icmp_seq=32 ttl=64 time=0.864 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.10.1: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=0.687 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.10.1: icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=0.606 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.10.1: icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=0.723 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.10.1: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=0.671 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.10.1: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=0.671 ms
^C
--- 10.244.10.1 ping statistics ---
52 packets transmitted, 6 received, 88% packet loss, time 50999ms`

I refresh the page and look at the route table and the entry I added is no longer there, which now makes sense why the pings temporarily worked, but then stopped.  Somehow (and I'm scratching my head how) the route is being deleted.

Any help with figuring out why its being deleted would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this case was simple.  AWS wasn't deleting the routes.  Kubernetes "route controller" was as the routes I was adding weren't recognized by it.